# Show a login screen before content of a view controller on a tab bar

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an application that will, by default, allow users to use the app in a guest or logged in state. When the user launches the application, the root view controller is a tab bar controller with three tabs. To access the features of one of the tabs, the user must first authenticate using an email and password. Currently, when the tab is pressed, the login view is shown using a push segue and I do not like the look of the animation, as well as the fact that you can temporarily see the actual logged-in view during the animation.

I have attempted add a navigation controller as a tab, then set the root view controller of the navigation controller to the logged in page, with a segue to the login page (the part I don't like). Instead I would like it so that there is no segue and the login page is shows with the tab bar at the bottom, and when the user is logged in, the logged in page is shown with the tab bar at the bottom.

Here's what is in my TabController class:

```
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2 {
        if AppDelegate.isUserLoggedIn {
            let navController : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
            navigationController!.show(navController.childViewControllers[0], sender: self)
        } else {
            let navController = viewController
            navController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: navController)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to swift so feel free to provide any helpful criticism

Answer (score 0):

Let say 'Tab 3' is the authenticated tab.

What you have to do is to create a navigation controller like :

`let navController = UINavigationController(root: loginController)`

if the user is already authenticated, then you edit the controller :

`navController.viewControllers = [loginController, tabContentViewController]`

This way, when the user will click the 3rd tab, he will see either login or "Tab 3" content, without push animation

Comment: What you've described works appropriate in terms of no push, but when I edit the controller by restating which view controllers it contains ([loginController, tabContentViewController] it still only shows loginController. If i try redefining with only [tabContentViewController] it still only shows the root view controller regardless. 

This leads me to my next question. Is it possible to change the root view controller of a nav controller while it's being viewed? (i.e., the user logs in and the tabContentViewController pops up right away)?

Comment: func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

let contentView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabContent")
        
let navController : UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "authNav") as! UINavigationController

        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2 {
            if AppDelegate.isUserLoggedIn{
                navController.viewControllers = [contentView]
            }
        }
    }